# Transporting changes to disconnected system - git bundle?

Tags: git

I have two systems, one for test and one for production. They are disconnected and neither is connected to the internet.

I have made significant changes to my software repo, and the production environment needs to be updated. Both systems have a copy of the git repo set up. The code on TEST was tagged when last transported to PROD (`1.4.0`), but we had to make emergency changes on the PROD system. These were then backported to TEST.

I intend to do the following:

On TEST:

```
git bundle create import.bundle 1.4.0..master
```

Then manually transfer the bundle to PROD.

On PROD:

```
git bundle verify import.bundle
# assuming all is well
git remote add import /path/to/import.bundle
git pull import master
# ...fix any merge conflicts
```

Which, I believe, will give me a PROD system that is up-to-date, plus I can then repeat the `bundle create` step later with an incremental set of changes.

**Will this work?** Are the **problems** that those with more `git-fu` can see?

EDIT:

I could replace the `git pull import master` with a `git fetch import` and `git merge -X theirs import/master`. Might be preferable.

Update 6 years later: it worked. I wanted a subset of changes because this repository was massive.

Answer (score 0):

`git bundle` gives you the whole repository every time.  You do not need to add it as a remote, you can just pull from it directly (if I recall correctly).

You can also just have a bare repo on the USB disk.  The bundle is just a single file which is easier to handle outside of git.

Comment: My understanding is that `git bundle` can be provided with a `rev-list` argument that stops it being the whole repo.

Comment: This is in no way hinted in your question.  Consider clarifying.

Comment: I was merely clarifying functionality of the command that you seem unaware of. If you look at the first code block, you'll see me pass in the `1.4.0..master` rev-list parameter.

Comment: Very well.  Why only a subset of the whole repository?

Answer (score -1):

On TEST, bundle everything from 1.4.0:

```
git bundle create import.bundle master ^1.4.0
```

Then manually transfer the bundle to PROD.

On PROD:

```
git bundle verify import.bundle
# assuming all is well
git fetch /path/to/import.bundle master:master
# ...fix any merge conflicts
```

more info: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Bundling

Comment: This is simply a copy and paste from my own question...

Comment: @shearn89 Please recheck the question and the answer, they are similar but are not the same. I tried to help you with a solution that works. It is not a copy and paste. Also, I added a link for more info.

Comment: @negas Please recheck the question, I'm asking for opinions on whether the outlined approach would work. I know how to do the bundling, hence I provided the commands.