# Synchronizing two git clones without push access

Tags: linux, git, synchronization

There's a server which hosts a git repo. I have two computers which I code from and have created a git clone on both. I frequently pull to get updates and new files. However, I cannot push to this repo (I can only pull).

I would like the files to be in sync across thee two devices so I can pick up where I left off on the other. How can I accomplish this (without creating another repo)?

Comment: If the two computers are named X and Y, add Y as a "remote" for X (so that you get `Y/master` etc on X) and add X as a remote for Y (so that you get `X/master` etc on Y).

Comment: If those 2 computers cannot be connected by network each other or to a 3rd one to serve as intermediate server, as suggested in the answers, but you can transfer files between them, you could use [bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914515/transporting-changes-to-disconnected-system-git-bundle) to synchronize the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'synchronize' two repositories if you do not have push rights.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your computers can access the other over ssh then you can push or pull directly between them.

If you don't have direct network access then you could in principle use Git's features for sending patches over email, but this will likely be more inconvenient than just setting up a third repository.